# Zurb Foundation: Semi transparent top bar possible?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

Is there any way to have a semi-transparent top bar with Zurb Foundation?

I have defined all the relevant variables, from what I can tell, in my `_settings.scss` file:

```
$topbar-bg-color
$topbar-bg
$topbar-dropdown-bg
$topbar-dropdown-link-bg
$topbar-dropdown-label-bg
```

And have tried all number of variations (of rgba's with alpha values from 0-0.5) and have always ended up with either a fully transparent bar or a semi-transparent bar with the dropdowns/buttons stacking their background on top and thus appearing darker/more opaque.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Is there any way to have a topbar that is semi-transparent throughout?

I can see in the stylesheet that `.top-bar-section li a:not(.button)` is always getting a background colour. I know I could manually override this in my own stylesheet, but I feel like there must be a way to setup the variables so these buttons don't appear darker?

Comment: What you're asking for is not reasonably possible if there are semi-transparent overlays involved.  The only way to make them not "stack" is to make the overlays completely transparent.

Comment: I just would have thought Foundation would provide a way to ensure the buttons/links in the top bar itself could be made transparent and have the long bar wrapper `nav.top-bar` show through

Answer (score 1):

The background on the links on the right side of your screenshot are being set by the `$topbar-dropdown-bg` variable. You'll need to change that to `none` or `transparent`.

The other steps are:

1. Set the background color variables to `none`.
2. Set the `$topbar-bg-color` to a semi-transparent value, like `rgba(#333,0.5)`.

Here's a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/VnH6e/)**. I've tried to comment all the variables I set the background to `none`.

Comment: I've been able to get the transparent topbar to look right in either full-width or mobile (small) width by editing the foundation_and_overrides scss, but never both transparent at the same time. Tried implementing your demo, but getting errors. I'm in Rails 4. Any experience with this or ideas? My nav is very basic with 2 links on the right and one on the left that drop down and work just fine, just not when trying to make them transparent. Thanks for any suggestions. @Brett

Comment: You shouldn't edit the foundation.scss files. You would want to edit the settings.scss file to change these variables.

I don't have experience with the Rails version so I can't give much help on that front.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
.top-bar { background-color: transparent; }
.top-bar-section { background-color: transparent !important;  }
.top-bar-section li { background-color: transparent !important;  }
.top-bar-section li a { background-color: transparent !important;  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following code, and sounds fine to me. I added few lines to Juni Brosas codes.

```css
header,div.contain-to-grid.sticky, nav.top-bar {
   
    background: none;}

    li.has-dropdown.a{background: none;}

.top-bar { background-color: transparent; }
.top-bar-section { background-color: transparent !important;  }
.top-bar-section li { background-color: transparent !important;  }
.top-bar-section li a { background-color: transparent !important;  }
```