# Foundation CSS Top-bar opacity

Tags: jquery, css, transparency, zurb-foundation, opacity

I am using Zurb's Foundation 5 to create a page, and I want to make the top-bar somewhat transparent. Any idea how this would be possible via css or jquery? Any code samples are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you linked your app.css after the foundation css file in your html and then add the following code to your app.css:

```
.top-bar {
      opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Set the opacity value as you want where it is a value lower than 1 and greater than or equals 0

Comment: Thats what my initial thought was, but it doesn't produce my desired results. See i have the page background setup as an image, and using the opacity 0.3 only declines the color, but the bakckground is still under, and can not be seen.

Comment: Try to use another values for opacity.

Comment: These settings only turn the background from a dark black to white when using different settings.

Comment: Check the CSS opacity definition from the following link to know what's this property offer to an element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and thought I would post my solution. After checking that my css file was correctly linked and the `.top-bar` opacity was either set directly or with an rgba value (e.g. `rgba(0,0,255,0.5)`), the top-bar was still not transparent.

My problem was the top-bar was wrapped in an element with a background set to a non-transparent color! Removing this solved the issue.

If you haven't made the same mistake as me, it could also have something to do with the topbar dropdown background colors - explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686128/zurb-foundation-semi-transparent-top-bar-possible) using the foundation Sass variables.